# how to do unit test elegant on graph operator

Tags: unit-testing

I have a application deal with graph computation. I want cover unit test on to it, but I found it is hard to do the test.

The main class is shown as follows:

- `Grid` store the graph strcture
- `GridInput` parse inputfile and save into `Grid`.
- `GridOperatorA` do some operation on `Grid`.
- `GridOperatorB` do some operation on `Grid`.

the production code is some thing like

```
string configure_file = "data.txt";
GridInput input(configure_file);
Grid grid = input.parseGrid();
GridOperatorA a;
a.operator(grid);
GridOpeartorB b;
b.operator(grid);
```

I found the code is hard to test.

My unit test code shown as follow

```
// unit test for grid input
string configure_file = "data.txt";
GridInput input(configure_file);
Grid grid = input.parseGrid();
// check grid status from input file
assert(grid.someAttribute(1) == {1,2,3,4,...,100}); // long int array hard to understand
...
assert(grid.someAttribute(5) == {100,101,102,...,200}); // long int array hard to understand
```

```
// unit test for operator A
string configure_file = "data.txt";
GridInput input(configure_file);
Grid grid = input.parseGrid();
GridOperatorA a;
a.operator(grid);
// check grid status after opeator A
assert(grid.someAttribute(1) == {1,3,,7,4,...,46}); // long int array hard to understand
...
assert(grid.someAttribute(5) == {59,78,...,32}); // long int array hard to understand
```

```
// unit test for operator B
string configure_file = "data.txt";
GridInput input(configure_file);
Grid grid = input.parseGrid();
GridOperatorA a;
a.operator(grid);
GridOperatorA b;
b.operator(grid);
// check grid status after opeator B
assert(grid.someAttribute(1) == {3,2,7,9,...,23}); // long int array hard to understand
...
assert(grid.someAttribute(5) == {38,76,...,13}); // long int array hard to understand
```

In my option, my unit test is not good, it have many backness

- the unit test is slow, in order to test OperatorA,OperatorB it need to do file IO
- the unit test is not clear, they need to check the grid status after operator, but check a lot of array is hard for programmer to understand what the array stand for. a few days later, programmer can not understand what have happened.
- the unit test is only for one configure file, if I need to test grid from many configure file, there will be even more array hard to understand.

I have read some technique to break dependency, such as mock object. I can mock the `grid` read from configure file. But the mock data is just like the data store in configure file. I can mock the `Grid` after operatorA, but the mock data is just like the grid status after operatorA. They will also leads to a lot of array hard to understand.

I do not know how to do unit test elegant in my situation. Any voice is appreciate. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the io

- you can pass something like a data provider to `GridInput`. In you production code it will read the file. In test code you can replace it with a test double (stub) that does provide hardcoded data. You already mention that above.
- you could also let "someone else" (i.e. other code) take care of loading the file and just pass the loaded data to the grid. Just looking at the Grid, testing gets simpler because there is no file handling required at all.

To make the test more readable you can do some of this:

- use nice test method names that are not just `testMethod`. Name them after what you are testing. You could use your comments as method names. Test only one aspect in a single test.
- replace the inline array with properly named constants. The name of the constants can help to understand what is checked at a given assertion.
- same holds for the parameters to the `someAttribute()` method.
- another option is to create you own assert methods to hide some of the details. Something like `assertThatMySpecialConditionIsMet(grid)`.

You could also write a test data generator to avoid hardcoding the arrays. Not something i would suggest for the first test. After a couple of tests a pattern ight get visible that can be moved to a generator.

Just a couple of hints to get you started.... :-)